# Bootstrap table contents are not aligned in every row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used the basic code of bootstrap in my code from here - 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_table-responsive&stacked=h

But the contents inside the  doesn't seem to be aligned. How to make them aligned? I am using bootstrap 3.3.4 version. Is this because of the version? If so, what's the fix?

Update: I put 25% in td but wanted to know if there is a better way

[image]

Comment: just add text-center in row so that everything inside the row is centered. you can user text-left as well.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately as how I want it!

Comment: Use bootstrap rows and cols instead of td. This way the page is responsive and will be aligned properly. If you cant code it I can help you with a sample code for it.

Comment: @ngawang13 yes I know how to write code for that. Thank you!